# Fill in the blanks: Reverse the original string without asking other than what is given?

Tags: c, string, data-structures

So here is an interesting question.

> Fill in the blanks of while loop without using any extra variables or functions of what is already given in program to reverse the input string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    int i=0;

    while( /*condition */ )
    {
       /*
       write code
       */
       i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n Reversed String: %s",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

My approach:

```
while(i < printf("%s",ch)/2)
{
       ch[i] = ch[printf("%s",ch)-1-i] + ch[i];
       ch[printf("%s",ch)-1-i] = ch[i] - ch[printf("%s",ch)-1-i];
       ch[i] = ch[i] - ch[printf("%s",ch)-1-i];
       i++;
}
```

Is there a better solution to it?

Comment: BTW `scanf("%s",&ch);` --> `scanf("%99s", ch);`

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Usage of `snprintf` as `strlen` : `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", ch)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY someone pointed out `snprintf()` is not provided in the exercise so i think using of `printf()` is more valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses the trite trick of swapping two integers X and Y without a temporary variable:

```
int x = 7;
int y = 11;
x = x ^ y;
y = x ^ y;
x = x ^ y;
// x and y are now swapped.
```

Here is the complete code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    int i=0;

    while(i < strlen(ch)/2)
    {
        ch[i] = ch[i] ^ ch[strlen(ch)-i-1];
        ch[strlen(ch)-i-1] = ch[i] ^ ch[strlen(ch)-i-1];
        ch[i] = ch[i] ^ ch[strlen(ch)-i-1];

        i++;
    }

    printf("Reversed String: %s\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the first straight C code I've written in over 5 years.

Comment: This will give an error as missing library to `strlen` and we cant modify outside of while. Thanks

Comment: Dont know what platform you used but codeblocks gcc compiler gave error , but still +1 for close approach.

Comment: @wrangler: Mac OS, LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42).

Comment: Is `strlen()` an extra function?  Is it allowed to use it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes its an extra function

Comment: @wrangler: `printf()` in the loop's condition and body is also an extra function, yes??

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes it is but in the question it is said we cant use other than what is given since `printf()` is used so we can use it again thats why i went for `printf()` rather than `snprintf()`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    scanf("%99s", ch);
    int i=0;

    while( 1 )
    {
        if(!*ch || !ch[1])
            break;//Processing is unnecessary
        while(ch[i+1])
            ++i;//search last position
        i <<= 8;
        while((i & 0xff) < i >> 8){//i & 0xff: front position, i >> 8: tail position
            ch[99] = ch[i & 0xff];
            ch[i & 0xff] = ch[i >> 8];
            ch[i >> 8] = ch[99];
            i += 1 - 256;//256: 1 << 8
        }
        ch[99] = 0;
        break;
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n Reversed String: %s",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ch[100];` should be `char ch[100] = "";`

Answer (score 0):

So here is a better update to my solution as suggested by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy).
Use of `snprintf()` instead of `printf()`. And i think this is the ideal solution to the problem.

```
//Reverse a string
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    scanf("%s",&ch);
    int i=0;

    while(i < snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",ch)/2)
    {
       ch[i] = ch[snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",ch)-1-i] + ch[i];
       ch[snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",ch)-1-i] = ch[i] - ch[snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",ch)-1-i];
       ch[i] = ch[i] - ch[snprintf(NULL,0,"%s",ch)-1-i];
       i++;
    }

    printf("Reversed String: %s\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This runs into the problem that `snprintf()` isn't used in the question. It depends on how stringently the 'no other functions' requirement is enforced. Using `snprintf()` is better than `printf()` — less noisy on the console, in particular. But if you can use `snprintf()`, why not `strlen()`, and why not extra variables. The exercise is modestly pointless; it's not how you'd do the job in real life (is it?). And having to repeat those calls to `snprintf()` — or `printf()`, or `strlen()` — should be worrying. The lack of any relation to reality means it is of limited interest as an exercise.

Comment: you are right sir, but its just an exercise nothing to do with real applications of it, its just make a person flexible in his way of thinking, there are many exercises that dosnt make any sense in real life but the purpose of that exercise is to train user to think beyond the box or limit him to think within the given constraints only. And i think the purpose of this problem is to **make user think within the given contraints**. Also you are right that `snprintf()` is not provided thats why i have provided the solution in my problem using `printf()`.